# How can I prioritise actions if I replace where my action would be by a routing variable?

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I currently have routing as follows:

```
resources.router.routes.tags.route = "tag/:tag"
resources.router.routes.tags.defaults.controller = tag
resources.router.routes.tags.defaults.action = index
```

However, if I want to go to an action in the tag controller it treats it as a variable and goes to tag/index, is there a way to make it check if there is an action defined first and if not, then map to that route?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest do use `__call`

Define your route so that your variable's name is `:action`, thus it will by default attempt to route it to an existing action:

```
resources.router.routes.tags.route = "tag/:action"
resources.router.routes.tags.defaults.controller = tag
```

Now, it will obviously use any action previously defined.

In order to handle cases where an action does not exist, simply define `__call` in your controller:

```
public function __call($method, $args) {
    //do something
}
```

`__call` is automatically called whenever a method being called does not actually exist.

Comment: Cool idea.  But if I'm going to do that then the routing is pointless, because my controller is called TagController, so it'll do that routing by default?  Is call not already used by zend further up the inheritence?

Comment: Assuming you use the default routing, yeah it would go to TagController with that URL. I recall `__call` is not used in dispatching at least.